# HOG + Linear SVM + Python

Tags: python, svm

Can someone give some references for extracting HOG features (both positive and negative) from folders, saving these in two .xml files and using these in a Linear SVM for classification in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For people with similar problems, I found this tutorial for beginners

http://www.learnopencv.com/histogram-of-oriented-gradients/

http://www.learnopencv.com/handwritten-digits-classification-an-opencv-c-python-tutorial/